# I can click on element but cannot sendkey on it (python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I can click on element but cannot sendkey on it (python selenium) in this payment form :

```
    card_exiry = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
    card_exiry.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-cse='encryptedExpiryDate']"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    card_exiry.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='encryptedCardNumber']"))).send_keys('3023')
```

This is the HTML Code :

```
<input class="js-iframe-input input-field" id="encryptedExpiryDate" type="tel" maxlength="5" autocomplete="cc-exp" placeholder="MM/AA" aria-label="Default aria expiry date label" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ariaErrorField" data-type="gsf" style="display: block;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soved by this code :

```
    def type_order_credit_card1_information(self):
    # Enter the credit card number
    IwebElement_Element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[1]')
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(IwebElement_Element)
    test = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='encryptedCardNumber']")))
    test.send_keys(credit_card1_number)
    self.driver.switch_to.parent_frame() # To switch to the parent frame
    # Enter the credit card expiry date
    IwebElement_Element2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="adyen-card-container"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/label/span[2]/span/iframe')
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(IwebElement_Element2)
    test = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='encryptedExpiryDate']")))
    test.send_keys(credit_card1_expiry_date)
    self.driver.switch_to.parent_frame()  # To switch to the parent frame
    # Enter the credit card cvv security number
    IwebElement_Element3 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="adyen-card-container"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/label/span[2]/span/iframe')
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(IwebElement_Element3)
    test = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='encryptedSecurityCode']")))
    test.send_keys(credit_card1_cvv_number)
    self.driver.switch_to.parent_frame()  # To switch to the parent frame
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this is because you used `By.XPATH` to find the element?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking help from the below code -

```
# Import
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

action = ActionChains(driver)

Elem_Send_Key = card_exiry.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='encryptedCardNumber']")))

action.move_to_element(Elem_Send_Key).click().send_keys("XYZ").perform()
```

Comment: try only `action.move_to_element(Elem_Send_Key).click().send_keys("XYZ")` or action.move_to_element(Elem_Send_Key).send_keys("XYZ")

Comment: For the card number this code is working fine :
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[1]')))
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='encryptedCardNumber']"))).send_keys('4035501000000008')
but fir expiry date and cvv number not workng, i have change endex for 2 and 3 but not working
in katalon it have [selectFrame | relative=parent | ]] to swich between frame but i can not find solution for that

Answer (score 0):

First, in HTML code your element has id `encryptedExpiryDate`, but in the locator you define `//input[@id='encryptedCardNumber']`

Second, try to change `.presence_of_element_located`  to be `.element_to_be_clickable`

Try this:

```
card_exiry.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='encryptedExpiryDate']"))).send_keys('3023')
```